# Is it possible to access debugs using python without sudo?

Tags: python, linux, sudo

I have an application in the user space that needs to access debugfs.

How can I do it without running the application using sudo?

Thanks,
Erez

Answer (score 0):

It's possible, but someone with root-type access will have had to set things up to allow it...

From [DebugFS](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/filesystems/debugfs.html) in the Linux Kernel Documentation:

> Debugfs is typically mounted with a command like:
>
> ```
> mount -t debugfs none /sys/kernel/debug
> ```
>
> (Or an equivalent /etc/fstab line). The debugfs root directory is
> accessible only to the root user by default. To change access to the
> tree the “uid”, “gid” and “mode” mount options can be used.